# Messaging instanciated objects in another class in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using a UITableView within a UIPopover with the aim to set a property to an instantiated object i am using within the original ViewController class(from where the popover is launched). However I cant get access to the declared object(from within the ViewController class). I have tried to import the ViewController class to the popover class, but to no avail, the object just isn't visible within the Popover class. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your popover controller is just a wrapper to place a normal UIViewController in to give it that particular effect. Therefore, to get your variable in scope in the popover controller, you need to set up your UIViewController subclass with a property.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Thing *thing;
```

So your Main view which is calling the popover will initialize the UIViewController with the property above, and pass it into the init method for the UIPopoverController and proceed as normal.

Comment: Thanks DVG, but i think i wasn't very clear. As the variable i want to bring into scope, is actually within another view controller, and not the one wrapped in the popover. So I need to access an objects properties from outside of its normal scope. Should I make this particular variable, which is just a simple integer to a global variable you think, or is there a more specific way or bringing externally declared objects into scope.